# javascript regular expression question mark after parentheses

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to capture some string only if it's appear so i use `?` after capture `()` meaning i want to capture that part of that string but it does not have to be shown (zero or one) but when i add `?` after `()` it drop that match:

```
var str = 'blablablacaptureblablabla';
```

if i make a regular capture with `()` i get the desire capture:

```
console.log(str.match(/.*(capture).*/i)); // array[1] = capture
```

if i add `?` to indicate capture may be or not be at all i get undefined:

```
console.log(str.match(/.*(capture)?.*/i)); // array[1] = undefined
```

why is that ? all i want is the capture the word `capture` whether its present or not in the string so this will not return null:

```
var str = 'blablablalablabla'; //string without word 'capture'
console.log(str.match(/.*(capture)?.*/i)); // this will work but if i use it with string with the word 'capture' it won't capture the 'capture'
```

**EDIT:**

Just to be clear - I want this string `blablacaptureblabla` to capture the word `capture` and also this string `blablablabla` to not return null cause i use `?` which means zero or one

Comment: Do you mean `console.log(str.match(/.*(capture|).*/i)[1]);`? So that Group 1 is always initialized with an empty string if `capture` is not present in the input?

Comment: If you move the `?` inside the capturing group parentheses it works: `console.log(str.match(/.*(capture?).*/i));`

Comment: @StephenP - but if i use it with string without the word capture like `blablablalablabla` it will return `null` on the match - which is not what i want since i want zero or one (`?`)

Comment: The capture group is, by definition, going to capture what it matches, so for `?` zero-or-one a match of one is the word(s) matched, and a match of zero ***is*** null — it didn't match the empty string, it matched _nothing_. That's how it works. The empty alternation `(capture|)` doesn't work here because it will always match the empty part _before_ it matches the longer _"capture"_ part, satisfying the alternation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want the capture value to be always initialized (to avoid `undefined` value for Capturing group #1) you need to use an *obligatory* group with an empty alternation *and* use the *tempered greedy token* `(?:(?!capture).)*`:

```
/^(?:(?!capture).)*(capture|).*/i
```

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/iD5kX6/1)

A [*tempered greedy token*](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#tempered_greed) is a special construct made of a (non-)capturing group (`(?:...)` or `(...)`) matching a single character that is not starting a specific sequence (that is specified with a *negative lookahead*, `(?!...)`), to which a quantifier is applied.

Below is a JS demo:

```js
var str = 'blablablalablabla'; //string without word 'capture'
document.body.innerHTML = '"' + str.match(/^(?:(?!capture).)*(capture)?.*/i)[1] + '"<br/>'; // undefined, as the group is optional
document.body.innerHTML += '"' + str.match(/^(?:(?!capture).)*(capture|).*/i)[1] + '"<br/>'; //  empty string, the group is obligatory
var str1 = 'blablabcapturelalablabla';
document.body.innerHTML += '"' + str1.match(/^(?:(?!capture).)*(capture|).*/i)[1] + '"';
```

Comment: But if i use the string: `var str = 'blablabcapturelalablabla';` with the word `capture` it still return empty match !! and i do want to match capture if there is capture

Comment: I updated the answer - the problem is that the empty alternation wins even with the lazy dot matching. I suggest using the tempered greedy token to "temper" the greedy quantifier and only match the text before "capture" that does not match "capture".

Comment: can you explain what `?!capture` means ?

Comment: `(?!...)` is a *negative lookahead*, and the whole construction I added is called a *tempered greedy token*. I added links in the answer. See also [*Regex disambiguation*](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-disambiguation.html): *Reducing `(? … )` Syntax Confusion* and [*Lookarounds*](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html).

Answer (score -1):

if you use the global modifier it will do what you want...

```
var str = 'blablablalablabla'; //string without word 'capture'
console.log(str.match(/.*(capture)?.*/ig)); // array[1] = ""
```

Comment: but i want to capture strings - with `g` modifiers the `()` is not capture - i have to use match without `g` modifier

Comment: what do you mean is not captured.. the `()` do define a capture group.. and is present in the index 1 of the array..

Comment: if i use the string: `var str = 'blablabcapturelalablabla';` with the word capture it still return empty string and i want to capture the word capture if its presented